# executorservice run last added tasks

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, android-asynctask, executorservice

I want to load images in a listview.I am using Executorservice but When scroll fastly, I want to stop and remove threads that in thread pool and  run last shown  cells tasks in screen(example : at the startup 10 cells are shown on screen) .How can I configure it?

note : it is forbidden to use third party libraries.

Comment: You can load pictures with Picasso or Glide or Fresco lib. It is very easy with couple lines of code.

Comment: it is forbidden to use third party libraries.

Comment: use `RecyclerView` and cancel your loading inside `RecyclerView.Adapter#onViewRecycled()` method

Comment: I mean  stopping and removing old threads  that run in pool  and  run last addeds

Comment: so stop and remove them inside `RecyclerView.Adapter#onViewRecycled()`

Comment: thank you @pskink it is usefull to solve my problem

Comment: sure, your welcome